# React Native - Changing Color of Custom Component Button with Prop

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, react-props, react-native-stylesheet

I created a custom component. onPress and title have prop method but I also want to add another prop for setting color. The structure I try to make is like below

```
<TextButton color="red" onPress=... title=... />
```

My custom TextButton component file is here.

```
const TextButton = ({ onPress, title, color }) => {

    return (<TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress}><Text style={[styles.helpButton]}>{title}</Text></TouchableOpacity>
    );
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    logButton: {
        fontSize: 18,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        padding: 25,
        color: {color}
    },
});
```

I couldn't find how to add prop to change one specific style. How can I add color as prop?

Comment: You can use it like `style={[styles.helpButton, { color }]}`.

Comment: So, how should color prop be fullfiled? I mean what's the rest steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by creating a new object based on the default style object.

```js
const TextButton = ({ onPress, title, color }) => {
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress}>
            <Text style={{...styles.helpButton, color: color || "black"}}>{title}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    );
};
```

It's good to add a default case, like, if you forget to pass a color, it just uses "black" as your text color. If you feel like this line is too big, you can extract that into a function, it would look something like that:

```js
const TextButton = ({ onPress, title, color }) => {
    const addColor = (style, color) =>{
        return {
            ...style,
            color: color || "black"
        }
    }

    return (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress}>
            <Text style={addColor(styles.helpButton, color)}>{title}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    );
};
```

Comment: I did like style={[styles.logButton,{color:color}]} and called as  <TextButton onPress={() => this.pressHandler()} color='#15DCA2' title='Button' />   I think same way.

Comment: It also works that way. But I prefer my approach because it's easier to add more logic, properties or default values. It has more readibility and mantainbility in my opinion